# Adding a custom nested UIView below UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am adding a expandale/collapsable UIView below UITableviewCell. I am able to add and hide the view on button action but unable to remove it when view is shown in another cell. I am updating the view height constraint to 0 on hiding.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)doneButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero 
toView:_tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView 
indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
CustomCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

for (int i = 0; i < [_expandedIndexPaths count]; i++){
   if (i != indexPath.row && [_expandedIndexPaths count] > 0){
       [self.expandedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
//Animation effect for expanding/collapsing view
       [cell animateClosed];
   }
}

if (sender.tag == 0) {
    [self.expandedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    [cell animateOpen];
    //[self.expandedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
}else{
    [self.expandedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    [cell animateClosed];
}
[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constraint update should also happen in the cellForRow method. Set the constant to 0 there.

> If you want the view to appear again for the cell that open it in first
>   place and didn't close it. Add hidden state boolean var in the cell
>   class and update every time you update that constant. Then on
>   cellForRow check the value of that boolean and set the constant
>   accordingly.